# OGG Converter Issues - Can't Contact Online-Convert

Tags: midi, ogg

I’ve been trying to contact the help desk at https://www.online-convert.com/help about an issue with their MIDI to OGG converter. Their web site doesn’t have a telephone number, e-mail or snail mail address, just an online form to communicate with them.

Unfortunately, that single method of communication is broken. I’ve tried over 10 times to send them a message over a couple of days, but the system fails every single time. All I get is the cryptic error message: “Something went wrong. Please try again later.”

Does anyone know how to contact this organization? I like their converters, as they yield some of the best quality OGG files I've heard, but if I can’t contact them for support, I may have to go elsewhere.

Any ideas on how to contact them would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: If cookies for their Website were blocked, the comment submission failed. Sadly, it took much trial & error for me to discover this. Would have been much simpler had their error message described the reason for the failure.